# La función Merge en R no funciona como quiero ¿como lo arreglo?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo dos bases de datos una con (130000 datos y otra con 42000) y necesito unirlas segun un codigo unico, comparten varias columnas en temas de contenido, pero les modifique el nombre o el formato fecha para que coincidieran exactas al momento de hacer el merge.

```
library(readxl)
library(readr)
library(chron)
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyr)
library(xlsx)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

consumo <- read_excel(direcciónbddd)
ventas<- read_excel(direcciónbbdd)

consumo1 <- select(consumo, Empresa, Nombre, Año, Mes, Alimento, COD_YCSE, Encontrados )
venta1 <- select(ventas, "G. Cliente", Centro,"Fc Ent", Entregado, CONC_YC )

consumo1$fecha <- paste(consumo1$Año, consumo1$Mes, sep = "-")


names(venta1)[names(venta1) == "G. Cliente"] <- "Empresa"
names(venta1)[names(venta1) == "Fc Ent"] <- "fecha"
names(venta1)[names(venta1) == "Entregado"] <- "Ventas"
names(consumo1)[names(consumo1) == "Nombre"] <- "Centro"
names(consumo1)[names(consumo1) == "Alimento"] <- "Consumo"
names(consumo1)[names(consumo1) == "COD_YCSE"] <- "CONC_YC"

consumo1 <- select(consumo, Empresa, Nombre, fecha, Alimento, CONC_YC, Encontrados )
# Convert the date column to a date object using as.Date
venta1$fecha <- as.Date(strptime(venta1$fecha, "%Y-%m-%d"))

# Extract the month and year using the format function and apply
venta1$month <- apply(venta1, 1, function(row) {
  date <- as.Date(row["fecha"])
  return(format(date, "%m"))
})

venta1$year <- apply(venta1, 1, function(row) {
  date <- as.Date(row["fecha"])
  return(format(date, "%Y"))
})

venta1$fecha <- paste(venta1$year, venta1$month, sep = "-")


consolidado2 <- merge(consumo1, venta1, by='CONC_YC')
```

mi problema es que al momento de hacer el merge, termino con un consolidado de 700000 filas aproximadamente ( cuando deberia ser un numero intermedio entre las otras bases) y me queda un resultado asi:

| codigo | centro.x | empresa.x | fecha.x | venta | consumo | fecha.y | centro.y | empresa.y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| codigo a | sede 1 | empresa 3 | 2022-01 | 400 | 500 | 2022-01 | sede 1 | empresa 3 |
| codigo b | sede 2 | empresa 3 | 2022-01 | 400 | 500 | 2019-01 | sede 2 | empresa 3 |

y yo necesito que quede algo asi

| codigo | centro | empresa | fecha | venta | consumo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| codigo a | sede 1 | empresa 3 | 2022-01 | 400 | 500 |
| codigo b | sede 2 | empresa 3 | 2022-01 | 400 | 500 |
| codigo b | sede 2 | empresa 3 | 2019-01 | 400 | 500 |

si alguien supiera como ayudarme lo agradecería

Comment: Antes de hacer el merge asegúrate de quedarte en cada datadrame las columnas que irán al dataframe de resultado lasnunicas columnas que deben estarben ambos son las del merge. En tu caso tienes la columna fecha en ambos dataframe y deberías quedarte con la que contiene el dato, en este caso consumo1 no debería tener la columna fecha pero venta1 si debería tenerla, por lo tanto obtendrás lo que quieras. En resumen, los dataframe deben tener las columnas que hacen el merge y las columnas se incluyen en el resultado.

Comment: Tienes centro, empresa y fecha en ambas por lo que el resultado les añade la x o y en función a donde están. Para que te funcione el meege me parece que debes quitar las columnas Centro , empresa y fecha de gonsumo  antes del merge porque estas vendrán del venta1. Centroby empresa es indistinto donde se queden pero fecha si debes quitarla de consumo1.

Comment: Estás haciendo `by='CONC_YC'` pero no se ve ninguna columna con este nombre ¿Podrías revisar el código y el ejemplo que compartiste?

Comment: Por otro lado, me parece que no es un merge lo que estarías necesitando ¿por que no haces un paso  atrás y defines en tu pregunta el problema original y no el problema que tienes con la solución que intentaste?